# Can't execute primefaces javascript in xhtml page

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

i am trying to use the filtering in primefaces datatable but seems like the javascript code of primefaces is not running.

code:

```
<p:dataTable value ="#{profil.profils}" var ="p" rows="5"
             paginator="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} 
             {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="3,5,15" resizableColumns="true" style="margin-bottom:20px" 
             widgetVar="profilsTable"
             filteredValue="#{profil.filteredProfils}">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('profilsTable').filter()" style="width:150px" 
             placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
```

error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

jars:

[image]

Comment: Please state what the results were when you posted the error in a searchengine.

Comment: it says that it's a jar conflict or the widgetVar has a different value than the one inside PF function but i don't have any of these!

Comment: If you are 100% sure about this (runtime classpath checked too, not just the 'build' classpath?), then please create a [mcve]. PF showcase works fine online and here.